# react native push notification cannot build

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I used react native push notification to view my notifications. but when i install this package this gets error building.
i used this github link to install

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

but when i run react native project it shows this error message in my linux pc.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it with SDK 26 or larger.

Comment: Can you show me the error?  Because i have used this library and it works for me.

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-push-notification'.
      > Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Try to update buildToolsVersion to 27.0.3 and if automatic "react-native link" command is not working then use manual approach to link react-native-push-notification library.

Comment: I refer this link i hope this will help you.     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQmudJLhPx8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181317/discussion-between-divyang-solanki-and-kalana-mihiranga).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to link react native push notifications manually in both Android and IOS .

Read this documentation for more informations :

[React Native push notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

You have to add code in android and ios folders and handle message reception in your MainActivity.java and AppDelegate.m and use both Android Studio and Xcode to add librairies .

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command on your project root "npx jetifier"

Answer (score 0):

There is **some issue at 7.2.*** version. Try moving to the latest version or any 7.3.* version. try this Command npm I react-native-push-notification@latest. then change in android/build.gradle.

1. Update to latest version. Using Below Command.
2. `yarn add react-native-push-notification@latest`
3. Also Change in android/build.gradle.

buildscript {
ext {
//  ...
firebaseMessagingVersion = '21.1.0'
}

Answer (score 0):

Update the package to its latest version:

```
npm update react-native-push-notification
```

And things will work

Answer (score 0):

in android/build.gradle add ..

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

    allprojects {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
                force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
            }
        }
```